Authjs's Google Provider for OAuth is not working in Nextjs
I am implementing Google OAuth via Authjs in my Nextjs project. In the same way I added Github OAuth but for google oauth, It displays an error. Here are some details of environment:
"next": "15.0.3",
"next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.25",
"react": "19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106",
"react-dom": "19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106"

# .env file
# Google OAuth
AUTH_GOOGLE_ID="########"
AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET="########"

# Github OAuth
AUTH_GITHUB_ID="########"
AUTH_GITHUB_SECRET="########"

// auth.ts
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";
import GitHub from "next-auth/providers/github";

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  providers: [Google, GitHub],
});


The Environment varables are loading, I have varified with console.log.
import { signIn } from "@/utils/auth";

export default async function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <form
        action={async () => {
          "use server";
          await signIn("github");
        }}
      >
        <button type="submit">Signin with GitHub</button>
      </form>
      {/* google */}
      <form
        action={async () => {
          "use server";
          await signIn("google");
        }}
      >
        <button type="submit">Signin with Google</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}


When I use the Github Button, It works perfectly but the Google OAuth is not working. I have double checked the callback, the client id and secret, they are correct. The Error it shows in the console when I click google button:
[auth][error] TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13392:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
    at async getAuthorizationUrl (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/.next/server/chunks/ssr/c1962_@auth_core_7c458b._.js:4386:35)
    at async Module.signIn (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/.next/server/chunks/ssr/c1962_@auth_core_7c458b._.js:4583:60)
    at async AuthInternal (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/.next/server/chunks/ssr/c1962_@auth_core_7c458b._.js:4890:24)
    at async Auth (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/.next/server/chunks/ssr/c1962_@auth_core_7c458b._.js:5120:34)
    at async signIn (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/.next/server/chunks/ssr/node_modules__pnpm_ac6287._.js:3971:17)
    at async action (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/.next/server/chunks/ssr/[root of the server]__89ce6a._.js:123:5)
    at async /home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:157:2088
    at async handleAction (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:156:20457)
    at async renderToHTMLOrFlightImpl (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:161:19013)
    at async doRender (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1568:34)
    at async responseGenerator (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1814:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1824:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:2240:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:2278:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:960:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:281:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:853:17)
    at async /home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:373:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:153:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:370:24)
    at async invokeRender (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:183:21)
    at async handleRequest (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:360:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:384:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (/home/myName/Projects/dummyProjectName/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.3_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106_react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106__react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:142:13)
 GET /api/auth/error?error=Configuration 500 in 71ms

I have tried many things to fix this issues but failed like implementing it using client component instead of server component, recreated the Google OAuth client with new id and secret, Clearing the cookies, etc

I believe issues with beta-versions should be reported as a GitHub issue because it's cumbersome to migrate an existing environment to next-auth@beta due to several breaking changes. BR
